# entity framework code first model builder

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api

In my `DbContext` class I have the following:

```
void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Properties<string>().Configure(c => { c.HasMaxLength(250); });
}
```

but also inside the `EntityTypeConfiguration` class for a specific model I have:

```
{
   Property(p => p.Name).HasMaxLength(500);
}
```

The problem is that setting the property to 500 inside the Configuration class is not taking effect and EF is still validating the max to be 250.

How can I have a general setting of 250 but override by fluent api as needed inside each class?

Comment: Have you add the `EntityTypeConfiguration` to `modelBuilder` in `OnModelCreating`?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. In EF6 (6.2 or 6.4) the configuration class overrules the added convention. Are you sure you add the configuration class to the model builder?

Comment: @GertArnold is the EF validation the length to be 500 or 250? in my case EF generates the migration as "500" max length, but it's validating the model to be max 250

Comment: @Kahbazi yes it's not shown in the code snippet, but I added it before and after (because I read online that EF does "last-wins", as in the last `modelBuilder` to be applied is the one that takes effect)

Comment: Can you share your ful OnModelCreating method?

Answer (score 1):

@Lutti Coelho: My mistake

Add code below in OnModelCreating method

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
                    .Property(p => p.StudentName)
                    .MaxLength(500);
```

Comment: The question ask specificly by **fluent api**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give a string field 500 characters.

You can do this by using the "**MaxLength**" attribute.

---

I am creating a sample table like the following.

My Context Configuration.

```
void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Properties<string>().Configure(c => { c.HasMaxLength(250); });
}
```

I am creating a table named FooEntity.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Foo.Model
{
    public class FooEntity
    {
        [MaxLength(500)]
        public string FooName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

After adding this attribute, the migration output is as follows.
Even if a 250 character limit is given, it will be passed as 500 characters in SQL.

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.FooEntity",
    c => new
        {
            FooName = c.String(maxLength: 500)
        });
```